# Python Dedupe Package Error: "Records do not line up with data model". But everything looks OK

Tags: python, python-dedupe

I'm following various tutorials for python dedupe online, but keep coming across this error whichever one I try:

```
ValueError: Records do not line up with data model. The field 'firstname ' is in data_model but not in a record
```

Somebody on their github had the same issue: https://github.com/dedupeio/csvdedupe/issues/55, and the dev said that the training examples have to have whatever record is in this error message.

My data has the `firstname` records, as does the fields variable.

Data to be deduped:

```
{76550: {'id': '76550',
  'title': 'mrs',
  'firstname': 'mary',
  'lastname': 'fakename',
  'email': 'fakemail@yahoo.com',
  'phone': None,
  'mobile': '353870748',
   etc etc etc}
```

and here are the fields:

```
fields = [
        {'field' : 'firstname ', 'type': 'String','has missing' : True},
        {'field' : 'lastname ', 'type': 'String','has missing' : True},
        {'field' : 'email', 'type': 'String','has missing' : True},
        {'field' : 'address1', 'type': 'String', 'has missing' : True},
        {'field' : 'mobile', 'type': 'String', 'has missing' : True},
        ]
```

The error is caused here:

```
# Pass in our model
deduper = dedupe.Dedupe(fields)

# Feed some sample data in ... 1500 records
deduper.sample(df, 1500)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-e34caa52a74c> in <module>
      2 
      3 # Feed some sample data in ... 15000 records
----> 4 deduper.sample(df, 1500)

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\dedupe\api.py in sample(self, data, sample_size, blocked_proportion, original_length)
    789                                a sample of full data
    790         '''
--> 791         self._checkData(data)
    792 
    793         self.active_learner = self.ActiveLearner(self.data_model,

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\dedupe\api.py in _checkData(self, data)
    802                 'Dictionary of records is empty.')
    803 
--> 804         self.data_model.check(next(iter(viewvalues(data))))
    805 
    806 

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\dedupe\datamodel.py in check(self, record)
    119                 raise ValueError("Records do not line up with data model. "
    120                                  "The field '%s' is in data_model but not "
--> 121                                  "in a record" % field)
    122 
    123 

ValueError: Records do not line up with data model. The field 'firstname ' is in data_model but not in a record
```

Both have `firstname` in them.

Where am I going wrong?

I have tried transposing the dataframe and converting to dict in all sorts of ways. I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that in your field definition you have an extra space

you want

`'firstname'`

not

`'firstname '`

Answer (score 0):

It's file encoding. In my case both files needed to be saved as UTF-8 with Unix lf otherwise Dedupe inserts extra spaces.